# Is there a way to induce a net negative electric charge in an electrically conductive material, and If not why?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

From what I've been reading, moving electrons don't compress relative to the protons within the atom, For reasons that I'm having difficulty understanding. Seeing that this is the case I would like to know if there is a way to create such a charge in a material. Please If you are going to use mathematical formulas, or physical laws/constants for you explanation, make an assumption that I don't have prior knowledge of them. I'm fairly inexperienced in this particular field of science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what a Van de Graaff generator does. The metal sphere at the top accumulates a net charge (actually I think the charge is generally positive in a VdGG but the principle still applies).

The electrons in a conductor are delocalised into bands, so the conduction electrons are not localised onto specific atoms but rather their wavefunction spreads out throughout the conductor. Adding a negative charge just means adding more electrons to the conduction band. These extra electrons are delocalised throughout the conductor just like the electrons already there. The extra electrons raise the energy, which is why if you earth the charged conductor the extra electrons flow off again.